# Funny issue with CSS and WebGrid

Tags: css, webgrid

Here is a funny problem that I encountered.

I am using *Asp.net MVC WebGrid* in my project. I am trying to apply some CSS to it.

So changed the code to

```
@grid.GetHtml(footerStyle: "pagination")
```

Now, the *pagination* class has some code like this

```
.pagination a:hover, .pagination a:active{
    border: 1px solid #2b66a5;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

So now, when I run this file and hover over the page numbers, the panel containing the table starts expanding! One row at a time!

I know I can't manage to get this kind of effect with just CSS if I tried. :p But I am getting it by accident! And it goes away only if I remove **both** the *border* and the *background-color* attributes.

I am just curious to know how is this happening??! Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Borders add to the size of some elements. For example, consider you have a `div` with a height of `800px` and a width of `400px`. If you add a border of `5px` to that `div` like so:

```
div.class {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
```

Then you'll notice that the box expands by `5px` in every direction; resulting in the box being `810px` by `410px`.

This can be avoided by using something like this:

```
div.class {
    border: 5px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This *should* solve your problem... hopefully!

Comment: I tried that, not luck. I had thought that the problem must be with the border but removing just the border did not help. It is some combination of these two attributes that is causing this.

Comment: That's really weird, I can't see why a background color would ever do something like this... Is it possible for you to recreate the issue in a fiddle or something similar?